# Google Analytics not showing steps properly

Tags: android, mobile, google-analytics

I'm working on a sample application on Android to send the Hits to Google Analytics, when i send the hit with an step number and product action ACTION_CHECKOUT_OPTION to Analytics it doesn't show on the Checkout Behavior Analysis. If I send the hit with an step number and product action ACTION_CHECKOUT it works fine. Here is my code:

```
public void sendCheckoutStepHit(int step, String action, String options) {

    Product product = new Product()
        .setId(mDinnerId)
        .setName("dinner")
        .setPrice(5)
        .setVariant(mDinner)
        .setQuantity(1);

    ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_CHECKOUT)
        .setCheckoutStep(step);

    Tracker tracker = ((BaseApplication) getApplication()).getTracker();

    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
        .setCategory("Shopping steps")
        .setAction(action)
        .setLabel(mDinner)
        .addProduct(product)
        .setProductAction(productAction)
        .build());
}
```

I'm using Google play services play-services:6.5.+.

The ACTION_CHECKOUT_OPTION is the one supposed to be accepting additional parameters for the checkout, why is that not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of play-services, as 6.5.x is quite outdated:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'`